# How to cluster this data

Tags: python-3.x, cluster-analysis, k-means

I tried K-means and Gaussian Mixture Models on my data set which is 160000 data points and has two variables.

When I run K-Means I get one cluster 's centroid in another cluster.

[image: Cluster scatter Plot]

Am I doing/plotting this correctly or this can happen in k means clustering?

The Steps I followed :-
1.) Outlier Removal using quantiles from raw data
2.) Applying transformations to normalise the rightly skewed data(log transformations on both variables)
3.) Scaling data columns (2 variables) to normalise it
4.) Fit train data using k means and predict number of clusters using Elbow Curve
5.) Predict on full data
6.) Plot scatter plot cluster and centroids wise
Code I used to plot the scatter Plot :

```
labels = model.labels_
centroids=model.cluster_centers_
plt.scatter(df_normalized['A'],df_normalized['B'], c=np.array(colors)[labels], alpha=.1)
plt.scatter(cent[:,0],cent[:,1],marker = "x",s=200,linewidths = 5, 
            zorder = 10,c=np.array(colors))
plt.show()
```

Im getting this cluster range on running k means with 4 clusters for A and B variables:-

```
           min      max
Cluster                
0        39507  1121667
1          241    57295
2        35807  1121323
3         3665   160919


              min        max
Cluster                     
0        4.222222  27.923077
1        1.076923   9.000000
2        1.076923   6.083333
3        3.500000  27.000000

Im getting this cluster range on running GMM with 4 clusters for A and B variables:-

            min      max
cluster1                
0          3992   142297
1           241  1121323
2         72785  1121667
3          1867  1119702

               min        max
cluster1                     
0         2.416667  27.923077
1         1.076923   8.375000
2         5.692308  27.923077
3         2.076923  10.000000
```

I had selected n components or number of clusters for GMM arbitrarily.I do not really know how to select number of clusters for GMM.

Is there any other method or algorithm I can use to segment/cluster my data so that most similar data points comes into each bucket.

My initial scatter plot of B versus A columns looks like this:-

[image]

Comment: I think there is a problem in the `np.array(colors)` and `np.array(colors)[labels]` part. Do check it again maybe? But individually plotting them (?)

Comment: I checked that that was correct, Im only concerned about the color of centroids if that code makes sense as in if it was mapped to correct clusters or not

Comment: Based on sklearn's documentation: Coordinates of cluster centers. If the algorithm stops before fully converging (see tol and max_iter), these *will not be consistent* with labels_.

Comment: I had taken only ```for k in range(1, 30):``` 30 iterations and saw SSE was steadily decreasing